# setup for multi platform app

Tags: deployment, mono, installation

Let's say you have an app in Mono .net implementation.

Now you want to create a setup - that targets multiple platforms(mac,linux, windows).

What would you use to create such setup? Are out there any oss projects?

Targeting only windows is easy - i would use WiX...

Answer (score 1):

Well, IMHO, most Linux users would mock you outright / would feel offended if you tried to ask them to run a "setup program", as most of them *always* do what I like to call the three command install.

Now, I'm not sure about cross platform compatibility, but `http://nsis.sourceforge.net/` (Nullsoft Install System) is my favourite.

Actually, come to think of it, the entire installer-setup program thing is pretty windows centric...